# Nested loops in coffeescript

Tags: for-loop, nested, coffeescript

This isn't working as I expected:

```
for sup in sups
  getStudents sup.CLKEY, (studs) ->
    console.log "Manager: #{sup.LNAME} Managed By: #{sup.MLNAME}"
    for stud in studs
      console.log "Student #{stud.LNAME} Managed By: #{sup.LNAME}"
```

getStudents receives each sup.CLKEY, but the rest of the references to sup return value from the last one in the array.

In other words, sup.LNAME and sup.MLNAME in the console.log statements are always from the last sup in the array

How do I nest the 2nd loop so that it stays on the current sup?

Comment: In case you are wondering why you need to do this, the reason is because you are declaring a function and that function, when *executed*, has access to the variables available when the function was *defined* (i.e. closure.) I've got a blog post that explains this in more detail if you are interested: http://hectorcorrea.com/Blog/Functional-Asynchronicity-Explained (the blog post explains it along with asych stuff but the main idea applies to what you are doing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding "do" made this work:

```
for sup in sups
  do(sup) ->
    getStudents sup.CLKEY, (studs) ->
      console.log "Manager: #{sup.LNAME} Managed By: #{sup.MLNAME}"
      for stud in studs
        console.log "Student #{stud.LNAME} Managed By: #{sup.LNAME}"
```

I couldn't get Kim's original solution to work (but it's since been changed to reflect using "do").

Answer (score 0):

Ow so you did it like this:

```
for filename in list
  do (filename) ->
    fs.readFile filename, (err, contents) ->
      compile filename, contents.toString()
```

Comment: Thanks!  I tried but this didn't work (threw some errors).  I had also considered passing sup as a parameter.  Fortunately adding "do" after the first loop seems to make this work the way I needed